# Display a grid of unrelated records on the form of an entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have 3 CRM entities: A, B and C. 
There is a 1:N relationship between A & B.
I have a custom activity D.
There is a 1:N relation between B and D

On creation of an instance of D, it's "Regarding" field set to an instance of C. 
C is not related to A or B directly via any direct relationship.

The question:
In the form for C, is there a way to somehow get to the ID of the instance Of A(via the "Regarding" field between C & D such as C --> D  --> B --> A) and use that ID of A to display a grid of related records of B on the form.

I'm guessing that this would involve an IFrame & javascript?

Comment: Can you simulate this view in an Advanced Find? That is, starting from A as a base entity, joining to B, then D, then C, and setting the instance of C equal to a particular ID of C?

Comment: Not sure I understand.The UI for this needs to be on the form for C.An example of your suggestion would help.

Comment: Never mind, forgot you needed this on the C form, but getting the `FetchXml` from the advanced find is useful anyway. (Included an answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods I know of.

1. [James has a good blog post @ The Dynamics CRM Green Bible](http://crmgreenbible.blogspot.com/2011/07/crm-2011-change-subgrid-fetchxml.html?showComment=1315336674024) about how to manipulate existing subgrids to display the `FetchXml` you need. This approach doesn't involve an IFRAME.
2. [Chandan shares a way](http://mscrm-chandan.blogspot.com/2010/06/advanced-find-view-in-iframe-in-crm.html) to use the Advanced Find view in an IFRAME that accomplishes a similar effect (written for Dynamics CRM 4, but easily adapted to CRM 2011).