# Creating Chart with custom programmatically altered FetchXML

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to create a bar graph that shows the # of accounts we've created in the past 3 months. I've tried using the Last X-Months query/view but as I've said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621727/last-x-months-does-not-function-correctly-in-crm-2011) it just isn't working the way I want it to. I did some searching and found another [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/01/19/custom-charting-capabilities-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) that could help me, in that it explains how to create a chart that relies on a web resource. If I created a web resource (JScript) that could programmatically create a fetch xml using the exact dates then I would be golden. I know how to create the fetch xml, the one thing I do not understand is how to inject it into the chart xml and get it to render. So basically I need to create a custom chart that relies on a web resource that will calculate the correct fetch xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using javascript, you can use Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) and the fetch extension (or native SQL, if you're using an on-premise installation) to create a chart/report that you can include in a dashboard or a form in the Dynamics client. You can then use VB to include anything created on or after the first of the month three months ago, or any other like logic.

[Richard Knudson has a blog post](http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/06/07/placing-reports-on-dynamics-crm-2011-dashboards/) dedicated to including reports in dashboards, [as does MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/02/28/reports-on-the-dashboard.aspx).

Comment: But aren't reports different than the charts (visualizations) ?

Comment: @Steve: They are, and so you lose out on the ability to customize visualizations. The report builder does allow for 8 different types of charts (bar, line, scatter, etc.), and among those types, many variations, and it speaks toward the basic requirement of creating a chart that meets your criteria, but they will more or less be statically created in your report (at least out of the box).

Comment: @Steve: As for passing in FetchXml to existing visualizations/charts, I'm guessing it's impossible, as the FetchXml seems to be encoded in the page source for charts.