# MSCRM 2011: Filtering an Iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have 2 questions regarding MSCRM2011 Iframe manipulation by javascript:

1. How can I filter a MSCRM2011 Iframe records using js? what I actually mean is having the Iframe display only records that meet some criteria. 
   (I know that it's possible to have this kind of filtering action while setting different filtered views through the Form customization page)
2. Is it possible to set the current Iframe view on a form, by js code?

Thanks in advance,
Ofer

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548048/display-a-grid-of-unrelated-records-on-the-form-of-an-entity/8549612#8549612 answer your question?

Comment: Peter, I explored the link you've provided, and used method 1 - it worked like a charm!! I really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1a) To pass information to an iFrame you can do so via parameters in the URL.  If you need to pass information back and forth, you need to do so using postMessage.

1b) Before going down the iFrame route, look at embedded grids.

2) Absolutely; however, with CRM 2011 you can place the iframe and just change the source.  It's really about personal preference.

If you want to inject it dynamically, you'll need to know the HTML you want to inject.  Something like:

`<iframe src='www.google.com'></iframe>`

Then set the Html of an item on the page to the iframe html code.

If you are wanting to piggy back the iFrame control (which is what I'd recommend in CRM 2011), then look to use:

`Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('IFRAME_opp').getObject()`

Here are some examples of working with iFrames that might help you (granted one is 4.0 but will relate if you are injecting):

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/07/adding-a-loading-screen-to-your-iframe.html
http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2012/01/crm-2011-iframes-saving.html

Comment: Paul, It seems that in my question I wasn't accurate, and actually meant for the embedded grids, and not for Iframe. I've found Peter's link from above helpful for that purpose, however wanted to thank you for your prompt reply.